# How do I modify my SQL query to output data only for Saturdays and Sundays within a specific period?

Tags: sql-server, date

I am running `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following query that runs fine. However, I need to modify it so that it outputs only `StayDates` that are `Saturdays` and `Sundays` for the period specified in the query.

I searched for a few solutions but I cam across some complex solutions that were hard to understand. Some mentioned using the `INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK` codes but with no clear explanation that would allow me to test the codes.

Here is how my query stands currently:

```
SELECT ResID, MIN(STAYDATE) AS 'Start Date',MAX(STAYDATE) AS 'End Date'
FROM RStayDate
WHERE StayDate BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY ResID
```

Instead of giving me all records that related to the specific period mentioned in the query, I need to modify the codes so that **ONLY** records which relate to week-ends (Saturdays and Sundays) are tabulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `DATEPART` function:

```
SELECT ResID, MIN(STAYDATE) AS 'Start Date',MAX(STAYDATE) AS 'End Date'
FROM RStayDate
WHERE StayDate BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-12-31' AND DATEPART(dw, STAYDATE) IN(7, 1)
GROUP BY ResID
```

@Richard has mentioned that it depends on settings, so you should check for it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

> When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value
>   depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST.

Comment: @Giorgi Works brilliantly!